# iOS: Object release in ARC environment

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, ios5.1

Could anyone please tell me am I handling memory correctly in following code in ARC environment? My concern is how would dict object released if I can't use release/autorelease in ARC! I know if it is strong type then it's get released before creating new one but in following look I don't know how would it works.

```
NSMutableArray *questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *q in [delegate questions]) 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:[q objectForKey:@"text"] forKey:@"text"];
    [dict setValue:nil forKey:@"value"];
    [dict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tag] forKey:@"tag"];
    [questions addObject:dict];
    dict = nil;
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are handling your `dict` correctly.

If you have a snippet like the following:

```
{
    id __strong foo = [[NSObject alloc] init];
}
```

When you leave the scope of the variable `obj`, the owning reference will be release. The object is released automatically. But it's not magic stuff involved. ARC will put (under the hood) a call like the following:

```
{ 
    id __strong foo = [[NSObject alloc] init]; //__strong is the default
    objc_release(foo); 
}
```

`objc_release(...)` is a sort of `release` call but since it bypasess objc messaging it's very performing.

Furthermore, you don't need to set the variable `dict` to `nil`. ARC will handle this for you. Setting an object to `nil` cause a reference to an object to disappears. When an object has no strong references to it, the object is released (no magic involved, the compiler will put the right calls to make it happens). To understand this concept suppose you two objects:

```
{
    id __strong foo1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    id __strong foo2 = nil;

    foo2 = foo1; // foo1 and foo2 have strong reference to that object

    foo1 = nil; // a strong reference to that object disappears

    foo2 = nil; // a strong reference to that object disappears

    // the object is released since no one has a reference to it
}
```

To have an understanding of how ARC works I really suggest to read [Mike Ash blog](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: A even better source for documentation is the llvm page: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: @mathk +1 for your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much both. It's very useful.

Comment: My advise is to think in term of ownership and not in term of retain/release. For full explanation see the documentation. Just a few message is returning an owning reference -init*, -copy*... For the other your should take care of when you want the ownership or not and ARC will just free you from calling the -release when you get the ownership of an object.

Comment: @mathk do you think I have to change some concepts in my answer? is it clear? maybe my english is not good enough... :)

Comment: I think you just have to change "strong" by "owning" reference a part from that I am agree with your answer

Comment: @mathk You are free to modify it if you want. I'll approve your edit. Cheers.